# How to declare the size of x and y - java

Tags: java, arrays

so for an assignment I've had to create a building class i was given the bare bones of the code and I've got this far the part I'm struggling on is setting the size of the x and y coordinate which needs to be in `setBuilding()`.

This is the desired output of the class:

- Building size 11×11
- Room from (0,0) to (5, 5) door at (3, 5)
- Room from (6,0) to (10, 10) door at (6, 6)
- Room from (0,5) to (5, 10) door at (2, 5)

The program displays everything apart from the "Building size 11×11", I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me just want to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks for any help

```
import java.util.*;

public class Building {
    private int xSize = 10;            // size of building in x
    private int ySize = 10;            // and y
    private ArrayList<Room> allRooms;  // array of rooms

    Building (String first) {
        allRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
        setBuilding(first);
    }

    public void setBuilding(String bS) {
        String[] Space;     
        allRooms.clear();
        Space = bS.split(";");
        allRooms.add(new Room(Space[1]));
        allRooms.add(new Room(Space[2]));
        allRooms.add(new Room(Space[3]));
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s;   
        s = " ";
        for (Room r : allRooms) {
            s = s + r.toString();
        }
        return s;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Buidling test\n");
        Building b = new Building("11 11;0 0 5 5 3 5;6 0 10 10 6 6;0 5 5 10 2 5"); // Create 
        System.out.println("built building\n");
        System.out.println(b.toString()); // And print
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're passing `"11 11; ..."` to `setBuilding(String)`, so the first element of `Space` would contain the building size. In that case you'd need to extract that data from the string like you do it for the rooms that follow. You might even be able to calculate the building size from the rooms you get although I'm not sure that's required.

Comment: Also, in `Building.ToString()`, add `String s = "Building size " + xSize + "×" + ySize;`

Comment: Btw, you should have a look at the [Java code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) to save yourself some headache and make it easier for us to understand your code and help.

Comment: In `setBuilding()` you should use a loop. What if the string contains more or less than 3 rooms?

Comment: Thomas - yes that is what im doing so would i do something along the lines of allRooms.add(new Room(Space[0])); but then how would i display the "building size 11,11" because as others have said i could just call the size from the x and y but then it would not link to the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't add any declaration to your toString for showing the building dimensions. I assume you want to use the `xSize` and `ySize` of the building. Also note that you're not extracting the building dimensions from the buidlString you pass to `setBuilding`.
Change your `toString` to the code below.

```
public String toString() {
    String s = "Building size" + xSize + ", " + ySize;
    for (Room r : allRooms) {
        s += r.toString();
    }
    return s;  
}
```

for defining your building size:

```
public void setBuilding(String bS) {
    String[] Space;     
    allRooms.clear();
    Space = bS.split(";");

    //Here we'll update the requested building size
    String[] buildingSize = Space[0].split(" "); //split the two integers
    xSize = Integer.ParseInt(buildingSize[0]); //transform the string to int
    ySize = Integer.ParseInt(buildingSize[1]); //transform the string to int

    allRooms.add(new Room(Space[1]));
    allRooms.add(new Room(Space[2]));
    allRooms.add(new Room(Space[3]));
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response but the x and y needs to link to the string so the "11,11; etc" so doing it that way would not work as if the string was changed it would not change the "building size" sorry if the way ive asked the question was wrong, im very new to coding

Comment: You need to use the first part of the string `11,11;` to set the variables `xSize` and `ySize`, I'll update the code in my answer

Comment: i keep retrieving errors when i try and run the code, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11 11"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at uCurtisBaldwin.buildingconsole.Building.setBuilding(Building.java:31)
 CurtisBaldwin.buildingconsole.Building.<init>(Building.java:22)
 at CurtisBaldwin.buildingconsole.Building.main(Building.java:59)

Comment: Change the `.Split(",")` to `.Split(" ")`

Comment: You're welcome! Could you mark the question as solved?

Comment: Done! really appreciate your help